# Ember js simple modal component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog

I want to make a simple ember js modal component. For this i use yield. As i understand yield renders the component's content into the div wuth the class modal. But it doesnt appearm only the overlay.

**modal component**

```
<div class="overlay" {{action "close"}}> 
</div>
<div class="modal">
  {{yield}}
</div>
```

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/dezuqalopumo/11/edit (click "dashboard")

Comment: Looks like ember is doing it's job. Bootstrap is setting .modal to display:none. Set it to block and it appears as expected

Comment: Thanks. it looks it was only that css problem.

Comment: for ember dont use jsbin, give embers version a try https://ember-twiddle.com/